# Running eclipse on a real device not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I've plugged my phone in via usb, and debugged it. I'll click on run, but it will just say none applicable under run as. If I unplug my phone and plug it back in, sometimes android application will be an option under run as, but it won't do anything. I'm new to this, so I'm not entirely sure as what to do. I have an S3 and I'm doing this on Mac OS X, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Do a right-click on the project folder (on a Mac that's ctrl-click), and from the context menu, select **run as... > an android application**.

This only works from the project folder, or from a package name, not from anywhere else. This Eclipse mouse context menu is very finicky that way.

What you described earlier had nothing to do with the actual plugging in of the phone. Yes, it's possible that adb/Eclipse couldn't see your phone, but even without a phone plugged in, you should still be able to **run as... > an android application** from your mouse context menu since you would use that same command to launch an emulator (or if no compatible emulator was present, that command would just launch an AVD Manager instead, that lets you create an appropriate emulator to do your testing on).

Comment: Just to add to this, you can also click on Run -> Run Configurations... and create a new Android Application Run Configuration.

Comment: @stephan Even if I do that and have an emulator that works and is open, it will tell me that "This selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

Comment: Great! I hope my advice was helpful.